# Transactional email

Tags: email

I found my package includes transactional email but I can not find any related tab/feature within the account?
Could anyone shows me where does the feature locates(under which sub menu)?

Comment: can you please more details to your question : which package you are referring to and what exactly you mean by transactional email ? any screenshot would be better.

Comment: I would like to get it clarify as well, as I found predictive email start as a sub-menu item under Emails, I was wondering if transactional email do the same. should have list under the email tab??